# Why did linguisticians choose 'Patient' (noun) to denote this Thematic Role? Why not Undergoer?

Tags: terminology

> THEMES and PATIENTS are rather similar, and not all linguists distinguish between
> these roles. A THEME typically moves from one location or one person to another,
> like *the letter* in (31). A PATIENT (or undergoer), like *the window* in (35), is physically
> affected by the verb’s action – so the window gets broken. A subject can also
> be a PATIENT, as with *the flowers* in (34): by wilting, the fl owers undergo a physical
> change of state, but they certainly don’t deliberately wilt, so that noun phrase is not
> the AGENT.

Maggie Tallerman, *Understanding Syntax* (2020 5 edn), p 49.

1. How's this sense of Semantic Role  related to the lay 2021 English sense of 'patient', i.e. a ["suffering, injured, or sick person under medical treatment"](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=patient)?
2. Why did linguisticians pick 'patient' to denote this Theta Role? Why not pick 'undergoer'  — that the author parenthesized  — that would be less polysemous, and thus less baffling, than 'patient'?

Comment: ‘Patient’ is the opposite of ‘agent’. If they’d chosen a different word for one, they’d have had to choose a different one for the other as well. As to why these particular words were chosen, I have no idea (I don’t know who came up with them), but they’re not particularly baffling. ‘A person or thing that undergoes some action’ is definition #2 in my dictionary, and that describes its role here quite well.

Comment: (Also, people who do linguistics are normally called _linguists_, not linguisticians.)

Comment: Also, people who do linguistics normally have studied Latin and know that _agent_ and _patient_ have been opposed in language and philosophy for millennia.

Comment: [Crosspost](https://languages.codidact.com/posts/285360).

Comment: really, linguists have *norm-ally* studied linguistics? https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/43618/have-linguists-normally-studied-latin?noredirect=1#comment99225_43618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Patient" is an adaptation of the Latin word for "undergoer", just like "agent" is an adaptation of the Latin word for "doer". This meaning of the word is found in all the dictionaries I've checked ([1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patient#Noun), [2](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=patient), [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20patient)) and is inherited from the classical grammatical tradition.

The modern meaning, "someone who is undergoing *medical treatment specifically*", is a later development.

EDIT: As Janus pointed out in the comments, "active" and "passive" (from the same Latin verbs) retain that earlier meaning.

Comment: And of course, the related adjectives _active_ and _passive_, derived from the same verbs, are more familiar and less ambiguous in their opposition and have no relation to medical procedures.